# What is DataContext for?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

As a continuation of the question [Linking DataContext with another property in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235403/linking-datacontext-with-another-property-in-wpf).

At the very end of the research I was very surprised to find out that when one writes something like that:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

The `DataContext` against which the `Content` property is binded is of the `Label` control itself! The fact that it still works is due to the default inheritance of the DataContext value from the nearest parent.

But if you have this label wrapped in a custom control, and you don't want to bind your data to the `DataContext` property of that control, you would more likely love to have:

```
<Controls:SearchSettings Settings="{Binding Path=Settings}" />
```

And here you are. Now you need to set `Settings` as the `DataContext` for the `SearchSettings` control, for `Label` inside to bind against, but you can't, because that will trigger re-binding of `Settings` property.

I can't see the point in mixing binding properties using different sources: `DataContext`, by `ElementName`, etc.
So why would I ever use `DataContext`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

When you write

```
<Label name="myLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

you are binding to `myLabel.DataContext.Name`, and not `myLabel.Name`.

The XAML in WPF is just a pretty user interface to display and interact with the actual data, otherwise known as the `DataContext`. The purpose of other binding sources (`RelativeSource`, `ElementName`, etc) is to point to another property that doesn't exist in the current control's `DataContext`

---

So suppose you have a Window. Without setting the DataContext, the window still displays but there is no data behind it.

Now suppose to set `myWindow.DataContext = new ClassA();`. Now the data that the window is displaying is `ClassA`. If `ClassA` has a property called `Name`, I could write a label and bind it to `Name` (such as your example), and whatever value is stored in `ClassA.Name` would get displayed.

Now, suppose `ClassA` has a property of `ClassB` and both classes have a property called `Name`. Here is a block of XAML which illustrates the purpose of the DataContext, and an example of how a control would refer to a property not in it's own DataContext

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow"> <!-- DataContext is set to ClassA -->
    <StackPanel> <!-- DataContext is set to ClassA -->

        <!-- DataContext is set to ClassA, so will display ClassA.Name -->
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />

         <!-- DataContext is still ClassA, however we are setting it to ClassA.ClassB -->
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ClassB}">

            <!-- DataContext is set to ClassB, so will display ClassB.Name -->
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />

            <!-- DataContext is still ClassB, but we are binding to the Window's DataContext.Name which is ClassA.Name -->
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=DataContext.Name}" /> 
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see, the DataContext is based on whatever data is behind the UI object.

**Update:** I see this question so often from new WPF users that I expanded this answer into a post on my blog: [What is this “DataContext” you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the detailed answer. But. What I don't like in you example is that you binding the DataContext property itself. Most probably I would extract StackPanel in your example into a separate control. It makes sense if its DataContext is just aт isolated part of DataContext of its parent, doesn't it? And then I wouldn't bind the DataContext property of my user control, but would rather have a special property with self-descriptive name. (I mean what is a DataContext for a particular control? What should I pass in?) And this is there the things get complicated. [To be continued]

Comment: As I would not bind the DataContext property, it would be taken from a parent control. Which means I am not longer able to bind controls inside my custom control against DataContext, just because I don't know what's in there (the control can't control whose child it will be, and what DataContext it will receive). The solution could be to set DataContext from inside to control (using a value from that special property). [To be continued]

Comment: But this will break binding of control itself, because, as you pointed out, having written `Content={Binding Name}` one binds to `Label.DataContext.Name` and not to `Label.Parent.DataContext.Name` as I would expect it to do.

Comment: @Eugene You want to make a new UserControl (Or DataTemplate) if it is logical to do so. Quite often that is not the case, and it is easier to bind something's DataContext than to bind to the same property multiple times.

Comment: @Eugene I would highly recommend you look into the MVVM Design Pattern. In my opinion it should be used with any WPF application, and you will get a better understanding of the DataContext and it's importance. Your visual controls are NOT your application - your DataContext (ViewModels) are. The visual controls (labels, buttons, textboxes, etc) are simply a nice UI that allows users to interact with your application.

Comment: That was a great article you've written on you blog. Highly recommend!

Comment: This is such a great answer. The problem 99% of WPF tutorials have is that they don't even attempt to explain what's going on internally. I'm a programmer, I need to understand the internals! It took me a while to even realise the XAML gets turned into classes somehow (although I still don't know how).

Answer (score 3):

From [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) by kishore Gaddam:

> `DataContext` is one of the most fundamental concepts in Data Binding. The Binding object needs to get its data from somewhere, and there are a few ways to specify the source of the data like using Source property directly in the Binding, inheriting a `DataContext` from the nearest element when traversing up in the tree, setting the `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` properties in the Binding object.

Detailed example on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case, you could do:

```
<Controls:SearchSettings DataContext="{Binding Path=Settings}" Settings="{Binding}" />
```

Assuming you want everything that may be content of the SearchSettings to use Settings as it's data context. Basically, the DataContext affects the element itself an any descendants that don't explicitly override it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you *do* want to bind to the DataContext, in some templates on ItemsControls it is the only way to bind to the currently templated item for example. Further bindings to the DataContext are nice to write and read as they are concise.

In your example you can still set the DataContext, you only need to modify the binding on the Settings respectively:

```
<Controls:SearchSettings DataContext="{Binding Settings}" Settings="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: I thought of this approach, but it doesn't make sense. Why should I bind two properties, if I only need one?

Comment: @EugeneStrizhok: You do not only need one, this allows you to bind to the Settings in the child controls without setting a source because you now can use the DataContext.