# .Net 4 WPF DataGrid's ItemsSource - works programmatically, but not declaratively

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I am writing a WPF program using C# and targeting .Net 4.0. I am trying to follow the MVVM pattern, where my view (code-behind) has minimal-to-no code.

I have a `List<MyRecord>` that I want to display in the GUI using a `DataGrid`.  In my XAML, I have the following:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RecordGrid" ...>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RecId}" Header="Record ID"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

All that's left is to bind this grid to a data collection.

When I bind it in the code-behind file, it works fine:

```
RecordGrid.ItemsSource = MyRecordList;
```

However, I would prefer to bind it declaratively in XAML.  So I tried this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RecordGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyRecordList}" ...>
```

but it silently doesn't work.  There is no XAML binding error message when the datagrid loads.  I set a breakpoint on MyRecordList's `get` method, and it's never invoked as long as ItemsSource is defined declaratively.

How can I get my datagrid to pull from `MyRecordList` via XAML?

Comment: Do you know what your DataContext is?

Comment: @default.kramer, I haven't set or changed my DataContext.  My entire test program consists of an Application and MainWindow.

Comment: You should probably ready [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262322/644812) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext if you want the binding to work...
The MVVM pattern has a View and a ViewModel. The *View* is your UI - e.g. the Window (Let's call it MainWindow) and your *ViewModel* is where you have the `RecordGrid` property and all theother commands/properties (let's call the class MainWindowViewModel)

You need to connect them both, This is done by specifying in your View, who the `DataContext` is (in our case the MainWindowViewModel class).

So you'll want to do something like this in your View's constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I normally do, but while playing with DataGrid I wanted to have everything in one file for simplicity.  I thought if I don't set DataContext on MainWindow, WPF will use MainWindow as the default context.  Seems like that's not the case.  So what's the default DataContext?  Is there one?

Comment: So if everything is in the same class, e.g. your Property is in the Window's code behind - use `this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: And if I don't -- what's the default?

Comment: There is no default, DataContext is an object and therefore null by default. Bindings won't work without setting a DataContext.

Comment: You wrote you have a `List<MyRecord>` -> Where did you declare it?

Comment: In the test program, I declared it as a member of the MainWindow class.

Comment: Then 1. Make sure it's a *Property* 2. Set the DataContext to `this` like I stated in my previous comment