# WPF: What is the difference between the Content and DataContext properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As I understand it...

- **DataContext** property

  - "controls use this property as a data source"
  - "is a property that each framework element has that can be used to flow data into the screen"
  - "DataContext has scope"
  - "the scope is established according to where the DataContext is assigned to in the object tree"
  - "if you set the DataContext on a parent element (e.g. a Window), that property will flow down to all child elements (e.g. a text box)"
- **Content** property

  - This property takes on many names depending on the control that is being used:

    - ContentControl.Content
    - ItemsControl.ItemsSource
    - Items.ItemsSource
    - HeaderedContentControl.Header
    - HeaderedContentControl.Content

So my question is: *what is the difference between the `Content` and `DataContext` properties*?  There is a nuance here that I am missing.  Is it...

1. While the `DataContext` flows data into the UI,
2. It is the job of the `Content` property to determine (usually threw a binding) what will be displayed (via ContentPresenter + ContentTemplate)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow" DataContext="{Binding ClassA}> 
    <StackPanel> <!-- DataContext is set to ClassA -->

        <!-- DataContext is set to ClassA, ClassA.Name will be displayed -->
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
 </Window>
```

**REFERENCES**

- MSDN: [ContentControl.Content Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- MSDN: [FrameworkElement.DataContext Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- MSDN: [WPF Content Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548.aspx)

  - worth reading
- StackOverflow: [What is DataContext for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262137/what-is-datacontext-for)

Comment: WPF has two layers. `Content` refers to the UI layer that is being displayed, while `DataContext` refers to the data layer that sits behind your UI objects. In your code sample, the `Name` property from the data layer is being pulled into the UI layer to be displayed in a `Label.Content` property :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DataContext` is a more general feature in WPF, as suggested by its ownership by the low-level FrameworkElement class.

- it participates in bindings for *all* framework elements, as the default binding source.
- as you mentioned, an element's DataContext is passed down to child elements.

`Content` is much more specific:

- it is a dependency property specific to a very limited set of controls (mostly those controls that inherit from `ContentControl` -- other controls such as `ListBox` do not own a Content property themselves, but *use* a ContentControl somewhere in their control templates).
- it is not passed down like the DataContext, but is rather concerned solely with the owning Control and its immediate relationships (ie, bindings)
- it is used by controls that call for something to be displayed, where the control itself does not know or care what type of object that will be.
- it is often used in cojunction with `ContentTemplate` -- that is, Content is *what* to display, and ContentTemplate is *how* to display it.  (`Button` is a good example of this.)

Comment: Thank you for your response McGarnagle. Using your analogy... from a binding point-of-view, would `DataContext` be *where* the data came from?  I'm assuming that the following won't work without a `DataContext` >>> `Content="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: @Pressacco yes, exactly right.  You can specify other binding sources (ElementName, RelativeSource), but DataContext is the *default* source.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check.  Just started learning WPF/MVVM 3 weeks ago.  Josh Smith and Plural Sight have become my new best friends :D