# Is it really possible to separate xaml and code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new in wpf and there is something that I don't understand..
Everywhere I am reading about separation of code and UI. So how should it work, even if I can design everything in blend, my code behind has always to react on changes and change visibilities in other situations... So first thing without the names of the controls, the code behind won't compile... And even if I have the names, isn't it far impossible to coordinate this?

Comment: Do a heavy reading on the subject "MVVM"

Comment: If you are naming a control, .... you are probably doing it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is a typical approach for WinForms where achieving a real separation of UI and logic is not possible as the application is driven by events hooked to specific controls.

However, in WPF you do not use (or don't have to use) events for the communication between UI and the application logic. Main areas worth investigating for you are:

- [DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262322/3330348)
- [Binding](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html)

Very broad overview is that the XAML describes the layout and specifies where the layout should get data from. Proper data are present in the data context and the WPF engine is responsible for all the wiring (or the *binding*).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" />
```

For instance in the code above the `Text` in the `TextBlock` will be populated with the value stored in the `Caption` property in the data context. (Usually the data context is specified on the level of a user control or user window.)
In the code behind there is nothing that is related to the TextBlock or to populating it with the values.

What you will find in the code behind usually is only initialization of the `DataContext`:

```
public partial class MyUiClass
{
    public MyUiClass()
    {
        this.Loaded += (sender, e) => { this.DataContext = new MyViewModelClass(); }
    }
}
```

All the data are stored in the class set as a data context (MyViewModelClass in the example above).

As a next step I would recommend to go through some MVVM tutorials (there is quite a few good ones on YouTube).

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the information! I red many articles but sometimes taking information over a short dialog , changes the point of view!

Comment: Not a problem. That's why I've recommend you to search for some tutorial on YouTube. You can follow it step by step and you see how the code got from one step to the other. In a written tutorial if you are completely new to a specific technology you can get lost between steps as the code may change too dynamically to follow. I'll try to dig up some good links later today.

Comment: This series is really good for beginners: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the "separation of code and UI" discussion, you aren't separating the *Xaml* from the Code-Behind.  Rather, you are separating the *logic* from the Xaml and, as a result, separating the *logic* from the *Code-Behind* as well.

When a Xaml control is constructed, not only is the xaml "view" constructed but so also is the backing partial class that initializes the control.  As a result, you always have a code-behind.  It's a fundamental part of how Xaml works.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in architecture you're talking about. 
You don't need *names of control* in the model data. The only thing model data interacts with are events/commands. In that way you have a separation between presentation and data where the model view is a bridge between those two.

Comment: Ok, I now you don't have to give ids or names like in windowsforms,or ASP.net.. But let's say you have an app where you are waiting on messages from a server and on every message type you have to change the visual design... The you have to access the controls from code behind, and how without names?  Thanks for answering!

Comment: No you don't need. You define UI templates, and orchestrate them based on the state of our model. You received signal about change in model, you change some variable and signal back to ui. UI responds on that signal by changing UI appearance and mapping loaded data to controls.

Comment: @Franki1986: to provide you with some basic starting point: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/control-templates-wpf