# WPF bind usercontrol to viewmodel from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Mainwindow** constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
captureUserControl.DataContext = MainViewModel.CaptureViewModel;
```

**XAML** in **mainwindow**

```
<UserControls:CaptureControl x:Name="captureUserControl"/>
```

Part of **usercontrol**

```
<Image x:Name="masterImage"  Margin="0,189,0,120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="{Binding Path=MasterImage, ElementName=captureUserControl}" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1" >
```

Part of **ViewModel**

```
public BitmapSource MasterImage { get { return masterImage; } private set {SetValue<BitmapSource>(ref masterImage, value); } }
```

**Error**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 
'MasterImage' property not found on 'object' ''CaptureControl' 
(Name='captureUserControl')'. BindingExpression:Path=MasterImage; 
DataItem='CaptureControl' (Name='captureUserControl'); 
target element is 'Image' (Name='masterImage'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

I think it might be because on creation the `captureUserControl` doesn't have its datacontext set until after its created. I want the `MainViewModel` to be instantiated in code behind because there's stuff that needs to be done that isn't a button click for example. Certain `async` methods need to be called on window load to initialize hardware. Does anyone have any examples or tips of the data bindings set up in this way?

Comment: The DataContext of an element is inherited by it's children. Did you try without the ElementName in you usercontrol's binding ?
A maybe related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262137/what-is-datacontext-for

Comment: yep that did it ;/ you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of an element is inherited by it's children.

The solution here is to remove `ElementName` from the Binding

A link for more details about DataContexts : [What is DataContext for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262137/what-is-datacontext-for)

Answer (score 0):

UserControls were not designed to be bound to view-models.

They were meant to be bound to other containers (i.e. Window).