# What is wrong with this WPF binding?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

The instance of the class is a private member of the view code exposed as a public property named "ViewModel".

Comment: Without looking, I can definitely say, "I don't know."  But I do know who does know--Snoop.  Get it and use it to debug your bindings at runtime.

Comment: Fools gonna fool.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the DataContext of the Grid to a string equal to "ViewModel". You need to make sure the DataContext property is correctly set to actual `ViewModel` object instance, either with a binding or via code behind.

For more information, see my answer to the question [What is DataContext for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262322/302677)

Comment: Thank you, Rachel!
Is this what you mean?

   <Grid DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}">
        <Button Content="Save" Command="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,276,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestName}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
    </Grid>

Comment: If you bind the `ViewModel` property, be sure the parent's DataContext is set to an object that contains the `.ViewModel` property. Typically I will set my application's .DataContext in the code behind (something like `MyApplicationWindow.DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();`), and have everything else use bindings or implicit data templates to inherit their .DataContext from there. The solution [posted by octavioccl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29826915/302677) would also work, although I personally prefer to avoid defining the data context as a static resource in the XAML like that

Comment: Thank you, Rachel. I think I prefer to have an instance of the ViewModel DataSource in the code behind as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with the Rachel's answer. An easy way to set the `DataContext` of your `Grid` could be this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <YourNamespace:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestName}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
</Grid>
```

This way you don't need to touch the code behind of your `Window`/`UserControl`.

If you don't want to change the code in your view and and want to keep your `ViewModel` property, then you could also do this:

```
Public Class View Inherits Window
   Private m_ViewModel As ViewModel
   Public Property ViewModel() As ViewModel
        Get
            Return m_ViewModel
       End Get
       Set
         m_ViewModel = Value
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Sub New()
      InitializeComponent()
      ViewModel = New ViewModel()
      DataContext = ViewModel
   End Sub
End Class
```

So you don't need to set the `DataContext` in your view, just do this:

```
<Grid>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestName}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
</Grid>
```