# WPF Binding to Class Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have xaml file:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Student.SName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And my Definition to this xaml file:

```
public Model.Student Student { get; set; }
```

And the `Student` Class which is in the property:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
    }

    private string _SName;
    private string _Name;

    public string SName
    {
        get { return _SName; }
        set
        {
            if (_SName != value)
            {
                _SName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
               _Name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do, to change the value in the Student-Property automatically when entering text?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad When i add info in .cs file View Update, but When i write text in TextBox it's doesn't update for me;(

Comment: Show us how do you set the  DataContext.

Comment: You can set "UpdateSourceTrigger " to "Lost focus"

Comment: @Peter i open windows as  View.AddStudent add = new View.AddStudent();
            add.DataContext = new AddStudentViewModel();
            add.ShowDialog();

Comment: Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the Bindings to `PropertyChanged`. It is `LostFocus` by default, which will trigger an update of the binding source (i.e. the view model) property only when the TextBox loses focus.

Comment: @Clemens thx so match but can i give me some sample for this?

Comment: `Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: @Clemens alas, it's dont work for me ;(

Comment: Just to clarify, you have an `AddStudentViewModel` class which contains a property for `Student`? And this is the property you are saying is not updating? Because in your question you say the definition of the `Student` property is in the XAML, which makes me think your DataContext is not setup correctly, and you are probably looking at two separate instances of the `Student` object.

Comment: @Rachel i write         public Model.Student Student { get; set; } = new Model.Student();
 and it's work! ;) Thanks!)

Comment: @user3588235 Be sure you understand what the DataContext is used for if you're working with WPF :) Here's one SO answer I wrote explaining it which you may find useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262322/302677